# Default selected checkboxes is not showing in the result

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a problem with default checked items. The default checkbox is working, but when i press a button to show all checked items, the default checks is not showing(they are showed like unchecked), but if i unchecked it and check it again, then it works. I can't find the problem, this is my code:

```
<ion-checkbox value="{{godina['title']}}" style="width: 200px;margin: 0 auto;" ng-model="checkItems[godina['title']]" ng-click="print()" ng-checked="godina.checked" ng-repeat="godina in godine">{{godina["title"]}}</ion-checkbox>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.godine = [
                  { id: 'Duh', title: '0',checked : false },
                  { id: 'Duh2', title: '1',checked : false },
                  { id: 'Duh3', title: '2',checked : true},
            ]
```

And this is js for all checked items:

```
 var array = [];
 for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
     alert($scope.checkItems[i]);
     if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
         array.push(i);
     }
 }
```

What i'm i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code for the button click and the corresponding JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a `ng-model` to track the values of the checkbox. What you can do is, simply track the selected checkbox on `ng-click` event by passing the entire object as a function parameter of `ng-click` and then checking if this object has been selected or not. And if the object (checkbox) is not selected then push this object on the selected checkbox array. But if it is already selected simply remove that from the selected array. Here is the code that works fine

```
 <ion-checkbox  type='checkbox' value="{{godina['title']}}" ng-click="print(godina)" ng-checked="godina.checked" ng-repeat="godina in godine">{{godina["title"]}}</ion-checkbox>
```

Controller code

```
$scope.checkItems = [];
  $scope.godine = [
      { id: 'Duh', title: '0',checked : false },
      { id: 'Duh2', title: '1',checked : false },
      { id: 'Duh3', title: '2',checked : true},
  ];
  angular.forEach($scope.godine, function(value, key){
      if(value.checked){
         $scope.checkItems.push(value);
      }
  });


  $scope.print = function(godina){
    var idx = $scope.checkItems.indexOf(godina);

    // Is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.checkItems.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // Is newly selected
    else {
      $scope.checkItems.push(godina);
    }
   console.log($scope.checkItems);
  }
```

Notice that loop. It is for pushing the already selected object in the selection array `$scope.checkItems`

For your simplicity. Here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/652/)

Comment: thank you, but the result is the same. when i open the page, the default items are checked. But if i didnt press anything, and if  i press save checked items, the result will be a blank array..

Comment: No it will not be blank array . On click on save check the value of $scope.checkItems inside that function. You will get the object for the default value selected on page load. check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j0bfe16q/ . Open your browser console and see. You will see the default value there.

Comment: oh, it works! Thank you man,i'm new at angular and when i lose 2-3 hours on thing like that..uf.. thank you one more time :D

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change ng- model value and delete ng-checked

```
<ion-checkbox value="{{godina['title']}}" style="width: 200px;margin: 0 auto;" 
ng-model="godina.checked" ng-click="print()" ng-repeat="godina in godine">
{{godina["title"]}}</ion-checkbox>
```